# How the inner working of Mode management is actually like?

Tags: major-mode

I'm aware of [some](https://www.emacswiki.org/emacs/ModeTutorial) [way](https://emacs-fu.blogspot.com/2010/04/creating-custom-modes-easy-way-with.html) to set up my own custom mode in Emacs, but I'm wondering: How does it actually manage Mode (eg: Setting things up, then resetting them once exiting Mode, etc)?

I'm guessing it probably work in either of the following:

- Using tempfile to remember state/Mode being used (either on disk or ram)
- Setting up mapping for both exiting and entering a Mode (while making it so they can check if Mode is already used or not)

If it's neither of these, then How the inner working of Mode management is actually like?

I'm mainly curious about it because I'm trying to emulate that for [another](https://vi.stackexchange.com/q/31353/30351) editor, and while I'm sure it's maybe out of scope for this SE, it probably isn't because *I'm not asking* how to do this, but merely how it actually work.

Comment: The question is too broad. It essentially says tell me something (what?), or everything, about a major mode - what happens when a mode is turned on. For that, visit the Elisp manual, node [Major Modes](https://www.gnu.org/software/emacs/manual/html_node/elisp/Major-Modes.html), and start reading. Or (or and) consult the source code. Then pose a more specific question, if you have one.

Comment: 1. What Drew said. 2. For what should the temp file be used for a usual major mode?? (Temp files can be used if the need arises.) 3. During the start up of a major mode (and also later on) one can set [buffer local variables](https://www.gnu.org/software/emacs/manual/html_node/elisp/Creating-Buffer_002dLocal.html). Those variables are [unbound when the major mode is changed (if they are not especially marked as "permanent local")](https://www.gnu.org/software/emacs/manual/html_node/elisp/Creating-Buffer_002dLocal.html#index-local-variables_002c-killed-by-major-mode).